# AttributeError: 'CategoryChannel' object has no attribute 'history' [Discord.py]

Tags: python, discord.py

I am using this code to get the total number of messages sent by a user on a server and storing it in a dictionary using channel.history but for some reason I'm getting an attribute error

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    dct_channels = {}
    dct_memb = {}
    for guild in client.guilds:
      a = guild.members        
      for channel in guild.channels:   
        dct_channels.setdefault(guild.name , [])
        dct_channels[guild.name].append(channel.id)
      for names in a:
        dct_memb.setdefault(guild.name , [])
        dct_memb[guild.name].append(names.id)
        
    channels = []
    users = []
    data = {}
    for i in dct_channels.values():
      for j in i:
        channels.append(j)
      
    for j in dct_memb.values():
      for i in j:
        users.append(i)
  
        
    for j in channels:
      channel = client.get_channel(j)
      async for message in channel.history():         
        for i in users:
          user = client.get_user(i)
          if message.author == user:
            data.setdefault(user , message.content)
            data[user].append(message.content)
            print(data)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get history only for text channels. Try to write the following:

```py
if isinstance(channel, discord.TextChannel):
```

In the for loop.

#### Your corrected code

```py
for j in channels:
    channel = client.get_channel(j)
    if isinstance(channel, discord.TextCahnnel):
        async for message in channel.history():
            for i in users:
                user = client.get_user(i)
                if message.author == user:
                    data.setdefault(user , message.content)
                    data[user].append(message.content)
                    print(data)
```

Comment: what does it actually return?

Comment: It returns `True` if `channel` is a text channel.

Comment: It will not bring history back to you. This will check if you can get the channel history.

Comment: oh okay, thanks man it worked